# In rails how to set a start date and an end date for date form fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set a start date and an end date to select using date_select or date_field or any other methods?

Comment: Did you go through the documentation of date_select or date_field?

Comment: @usmanali Yes. And I got the start year. I also want to set the month and the date

Comment: you can use `selected` or `default` in options, rather than `start_year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Rails [`date_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) official documentation:

> `:start_year` - Set the start year for the year select. Default is Date.today.year - 5 if you are creating new record. While editing existing record, :start_year defaults to the current selected year minus 5.

I'll leave to you the exercise of reading the documentation for `date_field` or *any other method*.

Comment: Yes I managed to get the start year. But not the month and the date

Comment: No, AFAIK you can't setup a time range with the default helpers.